# Vue CDN Script use state accross routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, cdn

Im using vue via CDN Script like this:

```js
const Home = {
    'template': `<h1>[[ $store.state.count ]]</h2>`,
}
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home
    },
    ...
]

const vuex_store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        count: 45,
    }
    ...
})

...
const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
})

const app = Vue.createApp({
    compilerOptions: {
        delimiters: ["[[", "]]"]
    },
    store: vuex_store,
    data(){ return {}}
    ...
})

app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

But I cant access either the `data()` or `$state` in routes except only the page the script is on.

I'm not using npm or any package manager, and due to certain constraints I'm stuck with this method.

How can I make this work? HAVE THE STATE/DATA SHARED ON ALL ROUTE TEMPLATES.

Answer (score 1):

the **`delimiters`** is not a global option so you must define it in every component you have

inside your **`createApp`** options saw the property **`store`** it's not the correct syntax for **`version 3`** of **`Vue.js`** you should use it like your router with **`app.use()`** syntax

for the final thing, you should use **`<router-view></router-view>`** in your HTML to render the output *(i guess you used but anyway)*

you can see a working example of your question in the below snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>use vuex in cdn way</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@4"></script>
    <script>
      const Home = {
        compilerOptions: {
          delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
        },
        template: `<h1>[[ $store.state.count ]]</h1>`,
      };
      const routes = [
        {
          path: "/",
          name: "home",
          component: Home,
        },
      ];
      const vuex_store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
          count: 45,
        },
      });

      const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
        history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
        routes,
      });
      const app = Vue.createApp({});
      app.use(router);
      app.use(vuex_store);
      app.mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```